# some problems with both vuejs 2 and webpack 4

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-4

I have a website coded with vuejs 2 and laravel.

Question 1-) I want to compress the codes, but my codes don't work properly on the site. Where could this error come from?

Question 2-) I don't think that i made the settings which i added below correctly. What would you recommend for me to check this?

Thank you.

vue.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const zlib = require('zlib');
module.exports = {
pluginOptions: {
compression:{
  brotli: {
    filename: '[file].br[query]',
    algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
    include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
    compressionOptions: {
      params: {
        [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 11,
      },
    },
    minRatio: 0.8,
  },
  gzip: {
    filename: '[file].gz[query]',
    algorithm: 'gzip',
    include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
    minRatio: 0.8,
  }
}
}
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const zlib = require('zlib');
module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
},
context: __dirname,
entry: "./src/app.js",
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), new HtmlWebPackPlugin(), new CompressionPlugin({
    filename: "[path][base].gz",
    algorithm: "gzip",
    test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0.8,
}),
new CompressionPlugin({
    filename: "[path][base].br",
    algorithm: "brotliCompress",
    test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
    compressionOptions: {
        params: {
            [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 11,
        },
    },
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0.8,
}),],

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.ext$/,
            use: ['cache-loader', 'babel-loader'],
            include: path.resolve('src'),
        },
        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                "style-loader",
                "css-loader",
                "sass-loader",
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader",
                "sass-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },

    ],
},
};
```

Comment: You're talking about the error in the first point. Could you then add the stack trace, please? If the issue with compression is resolved - post the answer please.

Comment: Whick stack trace do you mean?

Comment: So in your post, you're asking "Where this error comes from?" Looks like you forgot to add details of error. Overall, I was fighting with compressing at that point. And at the end resolved everything on Server settings side. If you want, I can write how...

Comment: I added the codes. It does not give an error and does not perform compression.

Comment: got it. I had the same issue. and found the solution. I don't compress files locally, however do that on the server. so for the end-users, the files are compressed and I am happy. if you're interested in the solution on the server, please, specify which one do you use.